# Find rows with duplicate/similar column values MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

I want to select from the following table all the rows which have similar values in the fname column as the first in their order. IOW from this table I want to retrieve rows with ids 2,5 and 7 (because " *anna*" comes after "*anna*", and "*michaela*" and "*michaal*" come after "*michael*").

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | fname      | lname    |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | anna       | milski   |
|  2 |  anna      | nguyen   |
|  3 | michael    | michaels |
|  4 | james      | bond     |
|  5 | michaela   | king     |
|  6 | bruce      | smart    |
|  7 | michaal    | hardy    |
+----+------------+----------+
```

What I have so far is this:

```
select *, count(fname) cnt 
from users group by soundex(fname) 
having count(soundex(fname)) > 1;
```

but since I'm grouping it the result is

```
+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | fname    | lname    | cnt |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | anna     | milski   |   2 |
|  3 | michael  | michaels |   3 |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
```

What I want retrieved is this:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | fname    | lname    | cnt |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  2 |  anna    | nyugen   |   2 |
|  5 | michaela | king     |   3 |
|  7 | michaal  | hardy    |   3 |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
```

What should I change about the query? I tried removing "group by" but it changes the results (I could be wrong, haven't tested it extensively).

Comment: are you sure you will get `michaela` and `michaal` both on soundex? I doubt, either of them you will get.

Comment: that doesn't matter, if it bothers you you can ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-read your initial question and I've came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  id IN
       (SELECT id
       FROM    users t4
               INNER JOIN
                       (SELECT  soundex(fname) AS snd,
                                COUNT(*)       AS cnt
                       FROM     users          AS t5
                       GROUP BY snd
                       HAVING   cnt > 1
                       )
                       AS t6
               ON      soundex(t4.fname)=snd
       )
AND    id NOT IN
       (SELECT  MIN(t2.id) AS wanted
       FROM     users t2
                INNER JOIN
                         (SELECT  soundex(fname) AS snd,
                                  COUNT(*)       AS cnt
                         FROM     users          AS t1
                         GROUP BY snd
                         HAVING   cnt > 1
                         )
                         AS t3
                ON       soundex(t2.fname)=snd
       GROUP BY snd
       );
```

It's a bit over-complicated, but it works and delivers exactly what you asked for :)

Comment: woohoo! that's exactly it. you rock! thank you so much. I really appreciate it, it will definitely save my a$$ at work :)

Comment: btw I've tried doing it myself, but it hasn't worked out. I tried completely removing the "AND id NOT IN" clause and instead providing the query with "id>min(id)" somewhere so it will only return the second row onward in order (which is what I want and seems a bit less convoluted). Do you have a clue how to go about that?

Comment: You can't go around GROUP BY returning only single ("aggregated") row if you're using GROUP BY at all. By using `id > MIN(id)` you'll still get only one row, but this time, second one, not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get what you're asking for - `SOUNDEX(fname)` would make Soundex hashes only from first name, not whole string. A few of options you can investigate:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(SOUNDEX(CONCAT(fname, lname))) AS cnt
GROUP BY SOUNDEX(CONCAT(fname, lname))
HAVING cnt > 1;
```

or

```
SELECT *, COUNT(SOUNDEX(fname)) AS cnt1, COUNT(SOUNDEX(lname)) AS cnt2
GROUP BY SOUNDEX(fname), SOUNDEX(lname)
HAVING cnt1 > 1 OR cnt2 > 1
```

It depends on what do you want to achieve: count of similar first name, last names or some synth hash of both.

Comment: This does not provide a solution to my problem, reread the question please.